# how to make tableview like contact apps

Tags: iphone, objective-c

I want a do a tableview like in the contact apps, is it many tableView? There is a tableview controller or they just drag table in interface builder, how do you make vertical line in the cell, is it custom cell table view. That's a lot of question but just give me the main idea to do a tableView like this?

Comment: It's all standard stuff - just poke around in the UITableView documentation, and you'll find what you're looking for.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**[UITableView](http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/documentation/uikit/reference/UITableView_Class/Reference/Reference.html)**

Answer (score 0):

Look into subclassing UITableViewCell for something like this.

Comment: Yes I suppose you are right, you could simply add subviews to a UITableViewCell after you initialize it, but this may get messy if you are trying to recreate several different types of cell arrangements from the contacts app, I would use CG in drawRect to draw in the line, add a plain UIButton to make the left side of the cell bring up the "home" / "work" option, and a plain text field for the text entry side, for the example of the divided phone number cell.